# Cannot debug Vine and Twitter api via charles debug proxy while facebook, flickr and any other API can be

Tags: ios, api, debugging, proxy, charles-proxy

I am trying to debug Vine API using Charles debug proxy. I have an IOS version of Vine app running in my device and I have set wifi proxy.

I could debug API calls from all other applications by enabling ssl proxying. But SSL proxying is not working for Vine(api.vine.com) . I tried twitter facebook and flickr apps. I could debug facebook and flickr apis and could see JSON response but for twitter this fails.

As Vine is owned by Twitter, my doubt is if Twitter has implemented some security in their APIs or changed some protocols to ensure that APIs cannot be debugged. If that is the case why facebook has not implemented the same ? Their APIs can be easily debugged.

Please find screenshots attached.

Vine API
[image: Vine API cannot be read by proxy. API succeeds and data is shown in app]

Flickr API 
[image: Flickr API]

Facebook API
[image: Facebook API]

Twitter API
[image: Twitter API]

### **UPDATE:Jul 22, 2015**

It seems that Twitter is [using SSL pinning](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/03/ssl-pinning-for-increased-app-security/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At last I found the reason. Twitter is using SSL pinning in their app to secure their APIs from man in the middle attack. There is a hint about this in their [API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/ssl)

More information about pinning can be found [here](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/03/ssl-pinning-for-increased-app-security/).

Comment: so was there a solution to it ?

Comment: No. App checks SSL certificate during authentication.App rejects the connection as SSL certificate, in this case, will be that of Charles proxy's

Comment: https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/ssl-connections-from-within-iphone-applications/

Comment: SSL Pinning

Note that some apps implement SSL certificate pinning which means they specifically validate the root certificate. Because the app is itself verifying the root certificate it will not accept Charles's certificate and will fail the connection. If you have successfully installed the Charles root SSL certificate and can browse SSL websites using SSL Proxying in Safari, but an app fails, then SSL Pinning is probably the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Frida https://frida.re to disable SSL pinning for any app. Check this: https://codeshare.frida.re/@pcipolloni/universal-android-ssl-pinning-bypass-with-frida/